# what may cause waiting state thread increase all the time in Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency

Today I found my Java 8 apps have many thread is in WAITING state:

```
[arthas@1]$ thread --state RUNNABLE
Threads Total: 3427, NEW: 0, RUNNABLE: 17, BLOCKED: 0, WAITING: 3114, TIMED_WAITING: 296, TERMINATED: 0                                                                              
ID             NAME                                         GROUP                          PRIORITY       STATE          %CPU           TIME           INTERRUPTED    DAEMON         
124            pool-11-thread-25                            main                           5              RUNNABLE       75             0:0            false          false          
53             as-command-execute-daemon                    system                         10             RUNNABLE       23             0:0            false          true           
133            Thread-20                                    main                           5              RUNNABLE       1              0:2            false          true           
28             Apollo-RemoteConfigLongPollService-1         Apollo                         5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
32             Attach Listener                              system                         9              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
99             DestroyJavaVM                                main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:39           false          false          
4              Signal Dispatcher                            system                         9              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
19             grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1                  main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
21             grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-2                  main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
97             http-nio-11003-Acceptor                      main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
85             http-nio-11003-BlockPoller                   main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
96             http-nio-11003-ClientPoller                  main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
54             lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1                     main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
70             lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-2                     main                           5              RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          true           
36             nioEventLoopGroup-3-1                        system                         10             RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          false          
42             nioEventLoopGroup-3-2                        system                         10             RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          false          
37             nioEventLoopGroup-4-1                        system                         10             RUNNABLE       0              0:0            false          false          
Affect(row-cnt:0) cost in 120 ms.
```

that have 3000+ thread is in WAITING state, now I pick a random WAITING thread pool thread, shows like this::

```
[arthas@1]$ thread 4410
"pool-96-thread-10" Id=4410 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3e27c029
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@3e27c029
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Affect(row-cnt:0) cost in 16 ms.
```

but the problem is I don't know where started the thread and what make the waiting thread increase. Is there any way to find out where to start the thread or why the WAITING thread increase? I am now using Java ThreadExecutor. Right now the waiting thread is up to 6000+. I add a custom config:

```
@Configuration
public class ScheduleConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(30));
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use a `ScheduledExecutorService` somewhere in your app, configured with 3000 threads, which isn't frequently having to run tasks?

Comment: I am using cron schedule in my project now . @BeUndead

Comment: Is it configured to be able to reuse threads appropriately?  Did you give it a custom `Queue` on creation, that can't hold anything and so creates a new thread each time?  Looks like it's consistently growing every minute.  Is anything CRON scheduled for every minute that might be erroring and leaving the threads in an unusable state?

Comment: My *guess* is that your code keeps creating **new instances** of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and never shutting them down. The code should only create one instance and then re-use it. That is the purpose of the thread **pool**, the reuse of the threads in the pool. In short, you have a resource leak, so go though the code and find where the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` object is initialized.

Comment: I did not find any `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class in my project, but I configuration the schedule task as multithread .@Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace you have shown is 'situation normal': That is a threadpool executor thread that is ready to do work, but the queue of work is empty. In this case, 'waiting' means: I'm waiting for a job to do, not: "I have stuff to do, but cannot do because I am waiting for stuff to be finished first".

Now, 3000 threads is itself somewhat of a concern; each thread has its own stack space. How large that is depends on your `-Xss` parameter, but they tend to go from 64k to 1MB. If it's 1MB, that's... **3GB** of stack space, that's... suboptimal. This number (how many threads you have waiting around for a job to accept) should also not be growing much after a VM has heated up.

If all/most of those WAITING threads have a similar trace, then there are really only two options:

- You made an executor and keep asking it, over time, to add more and more threads. I doubt this, but it's possible.
- You keep making executors. Don't do this.

The idea behind an executor is that you make only one, or at least very very few of these.

If you MUST create them as part of your running app (vs. the normal thing, of creating jobs and feeding them to the singleton executor), then be aware they are effectively resources: if you don't 'close' them, your process will require more and more resources, until eventually the VM will crash when it runs out.

To close them, you invoke `shutdown()` which is asking nicely, and `shutdownNow()` which is more aggressive and will any not-yet-picked-up jobs permanently undone.

So, to recap:

- You are making new executors during normal processing in your app. Search for `new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` in your codebase and inspect the situation. Add some logging if you must to see this in action.
- Then, most likely, you want to fix this and stop making new executors in the first place - just make one, once, and feed jobs into this one executor.
- If truly it makes sense to make them, use some guardian construct to ensure that you also clean them up when you're done using them. You can search for how to do so safely; it's a bit complicated, as you need to decide what to do with any jobs in the queue that are not yet done. If that's not an issue, it's easy: `.shutdown()` will get the job done.

Comment: Can creating new executors per every new incoming request cause an issue even after you are calling shutdown() after the request has been processed ?

Comment: Define 'issue'. I doubt it.

Comment: We are seeing high native memory utilization in our service . Heap size is not increasing.
On checking the threads in that container, I found out around 10k threads were created as part of new executor service objects . shutodwn() is being called for this executor service objects but still these threads were lingering.
Can they cause the native memory consumption to increase ?

Comment: A shutdown `Thread` object is generally like any other object; It'll be GCed when needed. Generally a java process always has high memory use: It'll claim it all and then manage its own heap. I don't think SO comments are going to lead to enlightenment here, I'm afraid - java memory management is a few orders of magnitude too complicated.

Comment: But can so many threads in waiting state due to creation of new executor service objects cause native memory consumption to increase apart from heap ?
That's what I am observing and trying to understand/validate

Comment: You said you shut them all down.

Comment: I checked code again. shutdown() is not being called for these executor service objects which is why these threads are forever lingering . But I am surprised why it is causing native memory consumption to increase apart from heap memory ? Are these threads allocated in native memory in Java 11 or heap space ?

Comment: Up to the JVM impl, but having a few million thread objects _running_ definitely causes quite a bit of load. Just fix your code instead of trying to figure out _if_ having hundreds of thousands of not-shut-down thread pools can be made to work.